# How can I make forward-sexp jump over one and just one pair of matching braces?

Tags: search, emacs

I'm working on an extensive set of elisp code which has accumulated over a longer time in my `$HOME/.emacs.d`. It's essentially fixes to make my life easier when programming or editing in LaTEX (Knuth would say that that is programming too ;-) )

So LaTEX allows you to define multi-parameter macros and I have a couple of effective macros to deal with change tracking, which goes by

```
\add{new} \delete{old} \change{old}{new}
```

Currently, I have an offline Python tool to accept or reject changes which handles recursive curly brackets quite nicely and I even have a simple macro packet for Emacs to handle `\add{}` and `\delete{}` using forward-sexp. When I started with `\change{}{}`, I noticed that putting the cursor over the first '{' and `(forward-sexp 1)` will move the cursor to the closing curly brace of `{new}`.

It that intended? If so, is there a way to make forward-sexp stop at the closing curly brace of `{old}`?.

Comment: Commands like `forward-sexp` depend on the definition of a sexp in the current mode. Check the syntax table, for instance.

Comment: I did that before asking and I don't see any difference in the Syntax of {} comparing cc-mode and tex-mode... This is why I'm puzzled...

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Please report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Try and provide a reproducible recipe (I couldn't reproduce your behavior in my Emacs with my config).